# Any downsides to compressing large folders in a Docker Image then extracting them in the entrypoint?

Tags: python, bash, docker, anaconda3

**Generalized question**

Is there any downside to compressing large folders in a Docker image and then extracting them at the container level in the image's entrypoint?

Cons:

- Not as reusable. (But assuming it's a one-off image this isn't much of a problem)
- Slow image startup due to the delay in extracting the folders.

Pros:

- Significantly smaller image sizes in some cases!!

Example dockerfile:

```
FROM some/image:latest
COPY ./venv.tar.gz .
COPY ./some_python_script.py .
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
 
  # if directory venv does not exist: extract it to root then remove the tar file
ENTRYPOINT  [ ! -d "venv" ] && tar xzf venv.tar.gz && rm venv.tar.gz || \ 
  # else: it already exists so we don't have to waste time doing it again
  echo 'venv already extracted from tar' && \
  # these always run
  source venv/bin/activate && \
  cd /app && \
  python "some_python_scipt.py"
```

**Why I'm asking**

I've dockerized an entire PyTorch geospatial training application excluding the data. However, geospatial training packages are MASSIVE not to mention the size of the PyTorch and Cuda libraries. The virtual environment for my image was 10.9GB alone resulting in a total image size of 11.5GB. That was also the optimized v-env using conda-pack in a multistage build. Compressing them beforehand reduced the image size to 5.2GB.

The running container clearly ends up being the original 11.5GB while it's running. However, the reduced image size makes it much easier to manage especially regarding speed when pushing and pulling from docker hub.

Complete gist exemplifying a compressed conda virtual environment: https://gist.github.com/NoahTarr/cdc0af59ebc84fc9d936eece35ebfaf7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest three problems with this setup:

1. In terms of local disk space, this will require 1.5x the storage space to run a single instance of the container, and then each additional instance will require additional space equal to the (large) size of the entire virtual environment.  That is, you need one copy of the compressed venv, plus one copy of the uncompressed venv per container.  If the uncompressed venv is in the image you will only need one copy of it across all containers.
2. Decompressing a large tar file will take time and this could make your container startup noticeably slower.
3. I've had practical problems `docker push` and `docker pull` individual layers larger than about 1 GB.  There are tricks you can do to make the individual layers smaller, for example `RUN pip install pytorch` before you `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`.  With this setup you have no choice but to have a single 5 GB tarfile layer.

For all that having been said, I'd believe this approach will fundamentally work; again, assuming you can `docker push` and `docker pull` it successfully.  The one change I'd make is to break out the complicated ENTRYPOINT line into a separate shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

# Unpack the virtual environment if it doesn't already exist
if [ ! -d venv ]; then
  tar xzf venv.tar.gz
else
  echo 'venv already extracted from tar'
fi

# Add the virtual environment into $PATH
. venv/bin/activate

# Run the main container CMD
exec "$@"
```

```bash
# Dockerfile
...
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["python", "some_python_script.py"]
```

This will let you do things like `docker run --rm your-image ls venv/python3.10/site-packages` to look inside the exploded tree without actually running your main application.

Comment: Yes, that all makes sense. I believe in certain applications, like ML in my case, this is the only method I could come up with to get the image to a somewhat manageable size.

Comment: In a previous setup, I had split large static data sets out of the actual image and injected them at runtime through a bind mount.  That helped bring the image size down to something manageable, though it also complicated the deployment mechanics.